# .bash_profile-like config file for windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

Looking for an alternative of .bash_profile-like configure file for windows command prompt, but no luck.

`alias` is main reason I would like to use .bash_profile. Currently I locate my own command in a specific folder and add folder path to %PATH%, it's quite not maintainable.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a .bat file with all your cmd stuff you want to run at the beginning of a command line session.

Then create a new shortcut with the command line:

```
 cmd /k c:\users\pandadrunkard\cmdsetup.bat
```

Then use the shortcut to open a new cmd session.

The `/k` switch will run the batch file, but keep the cmd window open for further commands, keeping anything you setup in the batch file valid for the session.